# How to access route params in route guard clause in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular-route-guards

I have an Angular 7 app in which I have a route like this

```
{ path : 'forgot-password/:resetHash/:email', 
  component : ForgotPasswordComponent, 
  canActivate : [ForgotPasswordPageGuard]},
```

Now I tried to access this route's `params` in it's `route-guard` but I didn't get route params in guard. Here is my `forgotpassword.route.guard.ts`

```
constructor(private _utilityService: UtilitySerivce, private _dataService: DataService, private _const: Constants, private _router: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
}

canActivate = (): boolean => {
    console.log('in link expiry guard')
    let userEmail = this._router.paramMap.get('email');
    let isAllow = false;

    console.log('params : ', userEmail)
    userEmail = this._utilityService.decryptMsgByCryptoJs(userEmail);
    console.log('user email : ', userEmail)
    this._dataService.post(this._const.userResetPasswordLinkExpiry, { email: userEmail }).subscribe(resp => {
        if (resp.success) {
            isAllow = true;
        } else {
            isAllow = false;
        }
    })
    if (isAllow) {
        return true;
    } else {
        this._utilityService.navigate('/login');
        this._dataService.exhangeResetPasswordObsMsg({ event: 'linkExpired' });
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it's giving this error

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Typo** alert: it's a **guard** - not a "gaurd" ....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`canActivate` takes the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` as its first parameter, so add that to your function.

```js
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean => {
    const email = route.paramMap.get('email');

    // the rest of the implementation
  }
}
```

`CanActivate` interface from [the docs](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

```js
interface CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): 
    Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree
}
```

EDIT

If you want to make an HTTP request inside your guard, you return `Observable<boolean>` instead. You can see that this is permitted from the interface.

```js
export class MyGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> => {
    const email = route.paramMap.get('email');

    return this.http.get('some url').pipe(
      // map response to some boolean value that determines the permission
      map((response): boolean => true)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: when i use `RouterStateSnapshot` so it's giving an error like this `NullInjectorError: No provider for ActivatedRouteSnapshot!`

Comment: Have you imported the routing module?

Comment: yes i have imported `RouterModule` in my app.module.ts and i am getting this error 
https://ibb.co/pJkCDr8

Comment: You shouldn't need router state snapshot if you just want to get params.

Comment: I didn't get your point. When i was using `ActivatedRoute` so you said that `canActivate` only uses `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` now you are saying that you don't need to use this? what do you want to say? please clarify in your answer

Comment: My answer clearly shows how to get params from within the `canActivate` function. Use this  signature: `canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean`

Comment: I added the full interface to show where it comes from

Comment: And i am telling you the same that i am using exactly your method and getting the error whose link sent above.

Comment: Are you trying to inject it into the constructor? Because `canActivate` is a function

Comment: You've not applied it in the way my answer said. `route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot` is the first argument in `canActivate`

Comment: can i make http call inside my route guard?

Comment: Yes. I will add to my answer

Comment: please answer my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60402486/how-to-make-http-post-call-inside-route-gaurd-in-angular7

Comment: Done. It's actually a bit more complicated that my update here, so worth a different answer