# How to make http post call inside route guard in angular7?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-route-guards

I have an Angular 7 app in which I have a post call and on the basis of that post call response I want to make guard active/inactive. I have my route guard like this

```
canActivate = (_router: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean => {
    console.log('in link expiry guard')
    let userEmail = _router.paramMap.get('email');
    let isAllow;

    console.log('params : ', userEmail)
    userEmail = this._utilityService.decryptMsgByCryptoJs(userEmail);
    console.log('user email : ', userEmail)
    this._dataService.post(this._const.userResetPasswordLinkExpiry, { email: userEmail }).subscribe(resp => {
        console.log('verify response : ',resp)
        if (resp.success) {
            console.log('in success')
            isAllow = true;
        } else {
            isAllow = false;
        }
    })
    console.log('allow flag  : ',isAllow)
    if (isAllow) {
        console.log('in allow')
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('in not allow')
        this._utilityService.navigate('/login');
        this._dataService.exhangeResetPasswordObsMsg({ event: 'linkExpired' });
        return false;
    }
}
```

But problem is that while my `http` `post` call is being in progress so my guard executes completely and returning false and after that response is coming from post call. How can I manage this scenario so I will make route true or false based on `http` `post` call response.

Comment: The problem is you are returning outside of a concurrent function and the code keeps evaluating. Return inside the post call instead of outside and return a ```Promise``` or an ```Observable``` instead of a boolean. CanActivate can return either of those -> https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: can you tell me in answer?

Comment: see my updated question i have updated my route guard. But now it's giving an error on line `canActivate = (_router: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean>`. Saying that `function must return a value`

Comment: Hii, You can use route  reolsver instead of http inside gurad.

Comment: you still need to return your call as a whole, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37948068/angular-2-routing-canactivate-work-with-observable\

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an Http request inside your `canActivate` function, you need to return an `Observable<boolean>` instead of a `boolean`, since you are now performing an asynchronous action.

And since you want to navigate on fail, you should return `Observable<boolean | UrlTree>` instead.

### Simple version

```js
constructor(private router: Router) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
  return this.http.post(url, body).pipe(
    map((resp: any) => resp.success ? true : this.router.parseUrl('/path'))
  );   
}
```

We are returning the observable http request (the router will invoke it by subscribing), and mapping the response to either a

- `true` - the router may proceed to the guarded route
- `UrlTree` - the router should navigate to the route we have returned

### Applied to your example

If we apply this to your example, we need to do a bit more work in the pipe, as you have an additional service call.

```js
// TODO: inject other services
constructor(private router: Router) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
      state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    const userEmail = route.paramMap.get('email');

    // I am assuming this is a synchronous call
    userEmail = this._utilityService.decryptMsgByCryptoJs(userEmail);

    const url = this._const.userResetPasswordLinkExpiry;
    const body = { email: userEmail };

    return this._dataService.post(url, body).pipe(
      // initial map from response to true/false
      map((resp: any) => resp.success),

      // perform an action if false
      tap(success => {
        if (!success) {
          // I'm assuming this is synchronous. If not, you will need to do a switchMap
          this._dataService.exhangeResetPasswordObsMsg({ event: 'linkExpired' });
        }
      }),
      // final map to boolean | UrlTree
      map(success => success ? true : this.router.parseUrl('/login'))
    );   
}
```

There are some service calls in there that I'm assuming are synchronous. This answer demonstrates how you perform an asynchronous call inside `canActivate` and either allow the router to navigate or return an alternative route to navigate to.

Comment: Now it is giving an error like this `Cannot find name 'UrlTree'.`

Comment: I didn't put *all* of the imports in there. If you are using VS Code you should be able to automatically import it. If not, you can manually import it from '@angular/router'

Comment: I have done with all imports but after that it's happening. Please see this https://ibb.co/tB3htqy

Comment: The error is on `canActivate`. You're still trying to assign a function to it by writing `canActivate = ()`. You just need to write it as normal class function `canActivate(/. params ./)`, just like in my answer.

Comment: see my updated question. I have updated my guard definition according to your answer but still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you take a bit of time to understand what's going on, and try to debug it. I've taken some time to give you a detailed answer. I can't debug your application via message board

Comment: please see this https://ibb.co/QQCDfYf . I have tried enough things that's why i posted here to get rid of this.

Comment: Ah, I copied a mistake over from your original post. I copied your function and then amended it, but didn't spot the mistake in the declaration. Remove the `=>` after `Observable<boolean | UrlTree>`

Comment: class functions should always look like this: `name(arg1: Type1): ReturnType { return returnType; }`

Comment: In your screenshot the `=>` is underlined as well as `canActivate`

Comment: yes it resolved me my rest of the errors but `canActivate` is still giving the same error. I don't understand why is it happening. Is it causing this error because i have 2 other gaurds in the same file?

Comment: Can you post your entire file to a stackblitz. That doesn't sound right

Comment: Even if it doesn't compile

Comment: yes sure. Let me do that.  see this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5ujgo4

Comment: It's complaining about `resp => resp.success`. Try `(resp: any) => resp.success`

Comment: Btw, I've rolled your question back to preserve the original problem.

Comment: i did all the things that you said but still getting this error https://ibb.co/2j1HzkW :/

Comment: Did you copy auth.service.ts into stackblitz?

Comment: My guess is that that's inheriting the class you've just updated, and now the signatures are incompatible. If so, that really is out of scope of this question

Comment: I copied all the code of file in which i have all 3 route gaurds which have classes name as follows  `UserAuth`,`AdminAuth`,`ForgotPasswordPageGuard`

Comment: the file that i copied to stackblitz to show you is named as `auth.service.ts`

Comment: Ah, I bet you need to add that second parameter: `canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree>`